# Signal Handling in UNIX

Tags: unix, signals

After registering to handle a signal. In the signal handler function is it necessary to call signal() again to re-register?

Comment: is it necessary to call signal() again to re-register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863420/signal-handling/4864889#4864889) answer. Or particularly [this](http://users.evtek.fi/~tk/rtp/signals-programming.html) link. 
Basically it depends on the model (BSD or System V) your unix system follows.

Extract from signal man page.

> In the original Unix systems, when a handler that was established using signal() was invoked by the delivery of a signal, the disposition of the signal would be reset
>          to  SIG_DFL, and the system did not block delivery of further instances of the signal.  System V also provides these semantics for signal().  This was bad because the
>          signal might be delivered again before the handler had a chance to reestablish itself.  Furthermore, rapid deliveries of the same signal  could  result  in  recursive
>          invocations of the handler.
>
> BSD  improved on this situation by changing the semantics of signal handling (but, unfortunately, silently changed the semantics when establishing a handler with signal()).  On BSD, when a signal handler is invoked, the signal disposition is not reset, and further instances of the signal are blocked from being delivered while the
>          handler is executing.
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
> - By  default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics.  This default behavior is provided as long as the _BSD_SOURCE feature test macro is defined.  By default, _BSD_SOURCE is defined; it is  also  implicitly defined if one defines _GNU_SOURCE, and can of course be explicitly defined.
>     On  glibc  2  and  later,  if  the  _BSD_SOURCE  feature  test macro is not defined, then signal() provides System V semantics.  (The default implicit definition of _BSD_SOURCE is not provided if one invokes gcc(1) in one of its standard  modes  (-std=xxx  or  -ansi)  or  defines  various  other  feature  test  macros  such  as _POSIX_SOURCE, _XOPEN_SOURCE, or _SVID_SOURCE; see feature_test_macros(7).)
> - The  signal()  function  in Linux libc4 and libc5 provide System V semantics.  If one on a libc5 system includes  instead of , then signal() provides BSD semantics.