# Why signal handler works only for my first ctrl + c?

Tags: c, signals

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void sigint_handler(int signo){
    printf("%s\n", "hello world!");
    for(;;){
        pause();
    }
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    for(;;){
        pause();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in action:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ gcc tugay.c
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ ./a.out 
^Chello world!
^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

Why don't I see the hello world message after I hit CTRL + C for the second, third, forth time..?

My understanding is the process should catch CTRL C again, but obviously it is wrong. But why?

Comment: The `man` page says: "The pause() function forces a process to pause until a signal is received from either the kill(2) function or an interval timer.  (See setitimer(2).)  Upon termination of a signal handler started during a pause(), the pause() call will return."

Comment: You should not be using something like `printf()` inside a signal handler anyway - you are recommended to only use "Async-signal-safe" functions as per the section with that name in the man page for `signal(7)`- the problem is because may functions that you might be tempted to use can them self generate further signals which can be catastrophic in handlers...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On BSD, when a signal handler is invoked, the signal disposition is
>   not reset, and further instances of the signal are blocked from being
>   delivered while the handler is executing.

And since mac osx is partly based on BSD, once the code is run on a mac osx, once second exception is called, it will be pending and wait for the handler of the first exception to exit. But since you will never exit, you have a deadlock.

Read my full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863420/signal-handling)

Answer (score 1):

Two facts:

- when a signal is delivered, it is also blocked during execution of the handler (no `SIGINT` will be delivered while execution is in `sigint_handler` if it is called from `SIGINT` delivery);
- `signal` is the *historical* interface, it is considered as obsolete, you must use `sigaction`.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this in The GNU C Library Reference Manual:

> When the signal is delivered, whether right away or after a long
>   delay, the specified action for that signal is taken. For certain
>   signals, such as SIGKILL and SIGSTOP, the action is fixed, but for
>   most signals, the program has a choice: ignore the signal, specify a
>   handler function, or accept the default action for that kind of
>   signal. The program specifies its choice using functions such as
>   signal or sigaction.
>
> While the handler is running, that particular signal is normally
>   blocked.